# IIS8: Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, httphandler, iis-8

There are lots of questions answering this, but none of the answers are working for me.

Originally, I was getting a 405 when I was trying to `PUT` or `DELETE`  (probably other verbs too).  Looking at some questions, the solution seemed to be to change the Handler Mappings.

I changed the following:

```
ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit
ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit
WebDAV
```

I noticed that the verbs were already in the `One of the following verbs` box, so in desperation I changed it to accept all verbs.

Now, I can't even load the webpage, let alone make any exotic requests like a `DELETE`, I immediately get a yellow screen of death:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +153
   System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +100
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +124
   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +76

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.]
   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +12687536
   System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry.SecureGetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +69
   System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry..ctor(String name, String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +66
   System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1 moduleList) +300
   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext) +1262
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +133
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +404
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +475

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12881108
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12722297

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18045
```

So far I have:

1. Checked ASP.NET 4.5 is installed via Web PI
2. Running `dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45`
3. Running `"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\ServiceModelReg.exe" -r`
4. Running `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -I`
5. More `iisreset`s than I can could
6. Replacing the `ServiceModel` in the `applicationHost.config`:

   `<add name="ServiceModel" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />`

replaced with:

```
<add name="ServiceModel" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

What else can I do, or where should I be looking?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 6):

you also have to activate servicemodel 4.0 with 
dism /online /enable-Feature /all /FeatureName:WCF-HTTP-Activation45

and in de IIS manager (server -> feature -> modules)
check if you see servicemodel 4.0 and then remove servicemodel.

Comment: the "/all" flag made the difference.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem after installing Synfusion Essential Studio on my computer. 
I resolved by performing the following steps:

1. Open IIS Manager console
2. On the Server panel go to Modules, features view
3. Make sure ServiceModule-4.0 is there. If it's not there, perform the steps prescribed above (1-6)
4. Remove ServiceModel module

Answer (score 1):

Just thought this might help someone.

This error can occur when there are multiple versions of the .NET Framework on the computer that is running IIS, and IIS was installed after .NET Framework 4.0 or before the Service Model in Windows Communication Foundation was registered.

here is the link to resolve this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh169179%28v=nav.71%29.aspx

Comment: Could you please edit your solution to include the info from the link?

Comment: While the linked site may help to resolve the problem, it is better to include the essential parts of the site here and provide the link for reference. Links can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

This link works for me.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/613812/Solve-IIS-Error-Could-not-load-type-System-Servi

You have to remove the ServerModel module and the svc-integrated handler.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to my application's web.config worked for me:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="ServiceModel-4.0" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Just gave me 500s.